# Как выполнить запрос на сервер до загрузки приложения

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-routing

Есть Angular приложение, необходимо выполнить запрос на получение пользовательских данных до загрузки всего приложения, т.е необходимо дождаться ответа от сервера, записать данные в ngRx storage и только потом загружать приложение.

**Для чего это нужно**:
Есть страницы админки которые должны быть ограничены и проверять авторизован ли пользователь,а эта информация должна приходить в ответе от сервера.

Или есть другие способы реализации подобного функционала?

Comment: а что не используете `fetch()` по религиозным соображениям? с анжела и fetch на одной странице - не комильфо?

Comment: Есть другой способ - загружаете страницу, блокируете, или не показываете те функции, которые относятся к администратору, в этот момент делаете запрос на сервер, получаете ответ и в зависимости от статуса ответа все разблокируете/оставляете заблокированным, или показываете/не показываете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать токен **APP_INITIALIZER**. [Статья с примером](https://blog.zverit.com/frontend/2017/06/17/app-initializer-bootstrap-service-method/)

Если вкратце, то в корневом модуле (например, app.module.ts) необходимо добавить новый провайдер:
`{provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useValue: () => promise, multi: true}]}`, где useValue - метод, возвращающий промис. Когда промис разрезольвится - приложение продолжит выполняться. Т.е. в useValue можно передать метод сервиса, отвечающего за инициализацию приложения, а в этом методе уже отправлять запрос, устанавливать состояние и выполнять прочие необходимые для работы приложения манипуляции. Главное по окончанию не забыть про resolve.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]